# Use process.env inside imported const in jest

Tags: import, jestjs, environment-variables, supertest

I have a config file that exports some info for my app.

```js
export const config: Config = {
  isProd: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production',
  connection: {
    port: parseInt(process.env.APP_PORT) || 2000,
  },
};
```

And I want to import it and use inside my e2e jest test.

```js
import {Test, TestingModule} from "@nestjs/testing";
import {INestApplication} from "@nestjs/common";
import * as request from "supertest";
import {AppModule} from "./../src/app.module";

import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config({path: ".env"});

import {config} from "../src/infrastructure/config/config"

console.log(process.env); // available here
console.log(config); // will return default values, not from .env

// ...
```

How can i make jest use env inside imported module?

Answer (score 0):

Nestjs has great configuration modules that support .env:
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#custom-env-file-path

Makes it really easy to ref your configuration in all of your services as opposed to having to import.